# How can i get content of FCKEditor using JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, fckeditor

I'm using FCKEditor. I am saving the form values with ajax but the content of FCKEditor value isn't saving into the mysql table. What can I do for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS

**JS**

```
var inst = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("description");
var sValue = inst.GetHTML();

if(sValue) {
    $("#showfckdatid").val(sValue);   
}
var formdata = $("#addfrmid").serialize();
var  request = $.ajax({
                   url:"<?=site_url("admin/content/add_act")?>",
                   type:"POST",
                   data:formdata,
                   dataType:"html"
               });
               request.done(function(data) {
                   alert(data);
               });
               request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
               });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="showfckdat" id="showfckdatid">
```

and add one hidden field in your form

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function GetData()
        {
            var inst = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("description");
            var sValue = inst.GetHTML();
            alert(sValue);
        }
    </script>
```